# Extract data from a mongoose object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, express, mongoose

I have a Shop Model

```
const Shop = mongoose.Schema({
  _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  shop_name: { type: String },
  products: {_id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,type:Array},
});
```

and a product schema

```
const Product = mongoose.Schema({
  _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  title: { type: String },
  description: { type: String },
  shop: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Shop" },
});
```

I'm trying to access a product within the products array of the Shop model, so that I can update it.

I've looked online a lot but couldn't quite find what I'm looking for. I need to access a very specific product within the products array with the given parameters, which are the id of the shop and the id of the product.

This is what I tried to do

```
const item = await Product.findOne({_id} , 'products').find({"products._id" : productId})
```

But what this does is it gives a mongoose object if the second find method hits a match

```
[
  {
    products: [ [Object] ],
    _id: 617f1bca39a5a43c1a981060,
    butik: 'scsbutik',
    butik_slug: 'egzbutikcom-1000010',
    butik_image: 'https://webizade.com/bm/img/butik-10.jpg',
    butik_points: '9.8',
    butik_order_count: 45,
    butik_success_order_count: 42,
    butik_refund_count: 3,
    is_butik_refund: true,
    __v: 0,
    login: []
  }
]
```

I need to access the object INSIDE the products array and update that product.

Appreciate any help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

don't use by default _id format I suggest declare a different value and then using populate method you can do it

```
const Product = mongoose.Schema({
shopId: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
title: { type: String },
description: { type: String },
shop: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Shop' },
 });
```

THEN ROUTING

```
const item = await Product.find(_id).populate('shopId')
```